# Error Entity Framework Database Changed

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I have started with ASP.NET MVC and the Entity Framework recently.

With an existing Database, I tried to map my classes to the database tables. Without success.

Let me show you my database tables:

-> **Categories**
--> Id (PK)
--> Title
--> Description

-> **Products**
--> Id (PK)
--> Name
--> Description
--> Price
--> Category (FK -> CategoryTree)

-> **CategoriyTree**
--> Id (PK)
--> ParentCategory (FK -> Category)
--> ChildCategory (FK -> Category)

Now, my classes for the Entity Framework:

```
class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTree> Category { get; set; }
}

class Categories
{
    public int categoriesId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class CategoryTree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categories> ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categories> ChildCategory { get; set; }
}

class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryTree> CategoryTree { get; set; }
}
```

**If I start the application, the compiler alerts the following error message:**
The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I hope someone can help me to understand this ;-)

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Application_Start() method of your Global.asax.cs, add the following line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);
```

That will stop Entity Framework from checking for changes to your model since the creation of your database.

Comment: Can you explain me the change checking? Why does he do it?

Comment: It's to let you know that your model is different than your database.  This makes more sense when the database was created by EF, and then you've added or removed a field or entity.

Comment: Then there is somewhere an error in my models? ;-)
Does the EF checks the property name, for sample Id, the it knows it's the primary key to map?

Comment: When EF creates the database, it also creates a table called _MigrationHistory.  Your model schema is stored as a hash in there.

Comment: Regarding ID and the Primary Key; yes, EF Code First knows if you call a field "ID", or "ClassNameID", that it is a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

For an existing database, I would suggest use [EF power tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to reverse engineering to generate POCO classes.

Comment: Another option is getting to know EF Fluent API, which allows you to have complete control over mapping by overriding OnModelCreating method in your context class.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see from the above information id `Categories.Id` in the db and `Categories.categoriesId` in the model (assuming no typo).

Also check the nullability of columns, for example `Product.Price` is nullable in the model, is it so in the db?

Can I also suggest, generate a new db with a different name from your model and compare to the existing db. The db name is specified in the connection string, so add a constructor to you DbContext class and pass the connection string in,

```
internal class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
```